# Pass the properties of a class to Access 97 query

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access 97 you can pass in a parameter to a database query by referencing the value of a form's control as in the following:

> SELECT *FROM tbl_rmc_audit WHERE emp_id = 
>   **Forms!frm_audit!cEmployeeClass.emp_id;**

Seems pretty similar to Access's normal way of doing business, but I can't seem to get the refernce correct.  If anyone can offer help, it is certainly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the query by setting the parameter to the value from you class in VBA.

Don't reference the form control in your query. Add the parameter [emp_id] to the saved query (Unless you are just creating a query in vba code):

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("query name")
qdf.parameters("[Same Name As In Query]" = cEmployeeClass.emp_id
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

Comment: Jeff, this has put me on the right track. I appreciate your comments.  Thanks a lot. c

Comment: Where are you using the query? If it's as the recordsource of a form or report, forget about parameters, and just use the WHERE argument of DoCmd.OpenForm or DoCmd.OpenReport. Basically, put as few restrictions on your saved queries as possible, and do the filtering at runtime.